# Bootstrap - load panel collapse

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have this bootstrap panel collapse with javascript, without a ID in the DIV because make a problem with others panels in the page.

This is my collapse panel and its not collapse when load page.

```
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
            <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
        $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
        $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    } else {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
        $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
})
```

And css:

```
.row{
    margin-top:40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.clickable{
    cursor: pointer;   
}

.panel-heading span {
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

How to load collapse panel when the page is load?

I hope to explain my problem
Thanks

Comment: Do you included `jQuery` ? What is `console error` ?

Answer (score 0):

just make it collapsed by default:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
        <span class="pull-right clickable panel-collapsed"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-body {
  display: none;
}
```